# Daynamically web application ,i create excel file in the folder and but i getting NPE

Tags: java, excel, jsp, servlets

I create a dynamic web application with jsp/servlet. I use a Excel file (udaanmasterdatabase.xls) to store data like a database.

The Excel file (udaanmasterdatabase.xls) is placed in source files (src files), and I can read the data. My problem is that when I run, I cannot  the Excel file in src folder. Can someone explain me why I cannot create this Excel file ?

```
// firstly i putting the excel file in src\com\roomantecheducation\excelsave
folder then i mapping in web.xml

<context-param>
    <param-name>MyAppHome</param-name>
    <param-value>com\roomantecheducation\excelsave\</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.roomantecheducation.controller.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

And the servlet,

```
// after that i putting the code as 

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{       

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
         ServletContext ctx = arg0.getServletContext();           
                    String  filePath = ctx.getRealPath("") + File.separator+ctx.getInitParameter("MyAppHome")+"udaanmasterdatabase.xls";
                System.out.println(filePath);
            ctx.setAttribute("filePath", filePath);
    }    
}

/*then excel file create and data inserted in excel file 
 i getting the null pointer exception here. but i give static path
like
 //   FileOutputStream out =  new FileOutputStream(new File("G:\\INVENTORY\\INDGLOBAL2\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\\tmp0\\wtpwebapps\\Roomantechnologyeducation1\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\roomantecheducation\\excelsave\\udaanmasterdatabase.xls"));
then excel file create but dynamically set in the fileOutputStream it getting error                       
*/

ExcelSheetController.java
    try
{

  String filepath       =       (String)getServletContext().getAttribute("filePath");                                                        FileOutputStream out =  new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath));  
                          workbook.write(out);
                                out.close();
                                System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");                                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Comment: .xls file is not exported in the .class folder... how are you generating the .war file?